# How can I implement a table?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Suppose you need to store some values ​​in a table formed by several columns (such as a relational database): for example, `int` for the first column, `string` for the second one, `DateTime` for the third one, etc..

If one or more column are like a primary key, then we could use an `IDictionary`, whose `Key` would be the set of fields that acts as a primary key. The remaining fields represent the `Value`. In this case I could create one or two classes/structures. For example, if the primary key is simply an existing type, we will only have to create a class/struct like the following:

```
public class MyValue
{
    public int Field1;
    public double Field2;
    public string Field3;
}
```

The dictionary could be a `Dictionary<int, MyValue>`, while the table could be the following.

```
public class MyTable
{
    private Dictionary<int, MyValue> _table;
    ...
}
```

Obviously, according to the application domain there may be ranges and/or rules of validity for the above fields: for example, `Field1` may have to be positive, and so on...

As a first alternative I could design the `MyValue` class so that it throws some exceptions in order to identify the "violation of rules". But perhaps this approach might be excessive, especially if the class `MyValue` is used only internally to `MyTable`: in this case I would write code like the following and handle validity error within `MyTable` class: that is, `MyTable` class checks the data fields before inserting them into the dictionary, so `MyValue` would be a "stupid" class...

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyValue
    {
        // only public fields
    }

    public class MyTable
    {
        private Dictionary<int, MyValue> _table;
        ...

        public void Add(int key, int field1, double field2, string field3)
        {
            // some code to check validity range for fields
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this solution correct? Or should I avoid this approach? Should I always define a class/struct in a complete manner (exceptions handling, `Equals`, `GetHashCode` methods?

Comment: This is so incredibly broad I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Do you have some link to some design guidelines (regarding this question) for .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let the values check their consistency themselves. If you implement the fields as properties, the setter can do checks and throw an exception is the value is out of range for instance.

I also would suggest a somewhat more flexible approach. Define an interface that your table records must implement

```
public interface IRecord<PK>
{
    PK ID { get; }
}
```

Records must have an ID, which will be used as primary key. We use a generic primary key type `PK`.

Now you can define a value class like this

```
public class MyValue : IRecord<int>
{
    private int _field1;
    public int Field1
    {
        get { return _field1; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 1000) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Value of 'Field1' must be between 0 and 1000");
            }
            _field1 = value;
        }
    }

    public double Field2;

    #region IRecord<int> Members

    public int ID { get { return Field1; } }

    #endregion
}
```

As you can see, it implements `IRecord<int>` and returns `Field1` as `ID`. `Field1` checks the values passed to it. If the primary key is made up of several fields you can use a type like `Tuple` (.NET 4.0) as primary key type. Like `IRecord<Tuple<int,double>>`.

Now you can define a generic table

```
public class Table<T, PK>
    where T : IRecord<PK>
{
    private Dictionary<PK, T> _table = new Dictionary<PK, T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _table.Add(item.ID, item);
    }
}
```

You can define specific tables like this

```
public class MyTable : Table<MyValue, int>
{
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Alternatively, you could let records implement an explicit error handling

```
public interface IRecord<PK> {
    PK ID { get; }

    bool IsValid { get; }
    string[] Errors { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you've done looks overly complicated, brittle and will ultimately lead to maintainability nightmares.

I'd say you have two options.

**Option one**: use a DataTable.  It doesn't have to be backed by an actual database and you can define it's layout (including column definitions) at runtime.

**Option two**: Define a class that implements your "record" logic.  Define a Collection to hold that class.  Use LINQ to "query" the collection for whatever you need.

The primary difference between the two options is that a DataTable is very limited in the type of rules you can employ.  Option 2, OTOH, allows you to build precisely what you want.

Comment: _Define a class that implements your "record" logic._ Basically this class should be a simple "set" of public fields: is it exact?

Comment: +1. *Why* ever consider such a thing at all?  No database back end? Working on a unified field theory of relational database integrity and business rules? Even so *why* reinvent the wheel?